# Asp.net Website hangs ocassionally under iis 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, iis-6, 3-tier

I have one 3 tier website published on IIS, it works fine but after some process run on website it gets hang and afterwards if i click on any other menu or link it hangs and no further response get generated. I am using one temporary solution, when I edit the Web.config from published DLL (Ex. add space in web.config or cut db name and save and then pasting db name  save) it works properly. This is getting too much hectic for use. Any permanent solution?

Comment: IIS6? On Windows 2003? You do know it went out of support several years ago? Anyway since you told us nothing at all about your application or environment (other than that you use an old, potentially insecure O/S for hosting), or any info from error logs etc, there is no way to meaningfully answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your info ADyson, we used .net 4.5 Framework hosted on IIS6. O/S we hosted our application on is Win 12. The Error log generated during affected proces is as follows: Error Message: ThreadAbortException

Exception Type: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException

Error Location : Thread was being aborted.

 Error Page Url: AbortInternal      If you have any solution after providing this info, then it will be helpful to us. Thank you.

Comment: That's quite a vague error unfortunately, it just means some threaded process stopped. Is there a stack trace? I would recommend a) stepping through the app with a debugger to see if you can reproduce it, and b) hosting on a supported platform (e.g. minimum Windows Server 2008 / IIS7)

Comment: Okay, i will consider above solutions.After implementing i'll revert back to you. Thank you.